# In javascript, i need a Regular expression to match balanced parentheses in a phone number /^([1]{0,1})\s?\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s]?\d{3}[-\s]?\d{4}$/

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, regex

The phone number may have:

- a starting `"1"` which is optional
- then `"Space"` which is optional
- then `"("` which is optional
- then 3 digits then `")"` then
- `"space"` or `"No space"` or `"-"`
- again `"("` which is optional
- then 3 digits then `")"`
- then space or No space or `"-"` and
- then `"("` which is optional
- then 3 digits

Eg1: `5555555555` or `555 555 5555` or `555-555-5555` or `(555)-(555)-5555`

Eg2: `1 555 555 5555` or `1555 555 5555` or `1555-555-5555` or `1-555-555-5555` or `1 (555) (555) 5555`

---

```
/^([1]{0,1})\s?\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s]?\d{3}[-\s]?\d{4}$/
```

The above regex is working fine on all the above but fails on the following examples which means that **I can't find that if I have only used an opening parentheses and no closing parentheses** for that then it also return `true` which should not! please help

e.g.: `1 (555-555-5555`
Eg: `555) 555 5555`

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: It would really help if you explained [why you want to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). What's wrong with just letting users type what they want for phone numbers? How do you handle international phone numbers like +44 1865 270000?

Answer (score 0):

The regex

```
/^1?[- ]?(?:(?:\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))[- ]?){2}\d{4}$/
```

matches exactly your examples

Live example: https://regexr.com/64iu7

Answer (score 0):

Let Javascript autocreate a regex according to a valid format list, will take care of any format of the phone numbers, as long the number is in the valid format list.

"Autocreate a regex via script" in context and testbench:

```
const validFormat = ["5555555555", "555 555 5555", "555-555-5555"
, "(555)-(555)-5555" , "1 555 555 5555", "1555 555 5555"
, "1555-555-5555", "1-555-555-5555", "1 (555) (555) 5555"];

let uniqueListTmp = new Set();

for(const s of validFormat) {
    let tmp1 = s.replace(/\d/g, "\\d");
    let tmp2 = tmp1.replace(/([\(|\)])/g, "\\$1");
    uniqueListTmp.add(tmp2);
}

let regexAsString = "^("; 
for(const s of uniqueListTmp) {
    regexAsString += s + "|";
}

regexAsString = regexAsString.replace(/\|$/, ")$")
const regex = new RegExp(regexAsString);

const invalidInput = ["555", "5 5 5", "5-5-5"];
const validAndInvalidInput = validFormat.concat(invalidInput);

for(const s of validAndInvalidInput) {
    console.log(s, ' -> ', regex.test(s));
}
```

Console output:

```
5555555555  ->  true
555 555 5555  ->  true
555-555-5555  ->  true
(555)-(555)-5555  ->  true
1 555 555 5555  ->  true
1555 555 5555  ->  true
1555-555-5555  ->  true
1-555-555-5555  ->  true
1 (555) (555) 5555  ->  true
555  ->  false
5 5 5  ->  false
5-5-5  ->  false
```