# Is there a way to fix this regex for splitting phone numbers?

Tags: java, regex

Well, a beginner here... I have this regex for Pattern.compile:

`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?:\\+?(\\d{1,3}))?[- ]?(\\d{1,3})?[- ]?(\\d{4,10})$");`

It is supposed to match these kinds of phone numbers:

1. +1 234 5678900 // This is how you dial internationally
2. +1-234-5678900 // ...
3. 001 234 5678900 // This is how you dial internationally using 00 instead of +
4. 001-234-5678900 // ...
5. 0234 5678900 // This is how you dial in the same country
6. 0234-5678900 // ...
7. 5678900 // This is how you dial in the same area

Now it matches and correctly splits the first four but when it comes to options 5, 6 & 7 I get this:

- `Country Code: 0234`
- `Local Area Code : 567`
- `Number : 8900`

And this:

- `Country Code: 567`
- `Local Area Code: null`
- `Number: 8900`

What am I doing wrong or missing?

The full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String phoneNumber = "+1 234 5678900";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?:\\+?(\\d{1,4}))?[- ]?(\\d{1,3})?[- ]?(\\d{4,10})$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(phoneNumber);

        while (m.find()) {
            printMatch("Country Code", m, 1);
            printMatch("Local Area Code", m, 2);
            printMatch("Number", m, 3);
        }
        
    }

    public static void printMatch(String label, Matcher m, int group) {
        System.out.printf("%-16s: %s%n", label, m.group(group));
    }

}
```

Comment: Is country code always separated from the rest of the number with a space or hyphen?

Comment: Yes, space or hyphen.

Comment: From what I see, `0` can be glued to the area code, so this won't help. Try `"^(?:\\+?(\\d{1,3}?)[- ]?)??(\\d{1,3})??[- ]?(\\d{4,10})$"`

Comment: I would say this is the best approach to handle phone numbers in various format: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68957158/in-javascript-i-need-a-regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses-in-a-ph/68971652#68971652

You make a list of valid phone numbers and let Java generate the matching regex for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  use

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?:\\+?(\\d{1,3}?)[- ]?)??(\\d{1,3})??[- ]?(\\d{4,10})$");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dho7CM/1). Note that if you use the regex with `.matches()`, you won't need the `^` and `$` anchors.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\+?(\d{1,3}?)[- ]?)??` - an optional (lazy) occurrence of an optional `+`, then one, two or three (but as few as possible) digits (Group 1), and then an optional `-` or space
- `(\d{1,3})??` - Group 2: one or zero, but as few as possible, occurrences of one, two or three digits
- `[- ]?` - an optional space or `-`
- `(\d{4,10})` - Group 3: four to ten digits
- `$` - end of string.

In Java code, you should use `if` instead of `while` as you only need the first match, see a [demo below](https://ideone.com/gWxe0F):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
 
class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String phoneNumber = "+1 234 5678900";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:\\+?(\\d{1,3}?)[- ]?)??(\\d{1,3})??[- ]?(\\d{4,10})");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(phoneNumber);
 
        if (m.matches()) {
            printMatch("Country Code", m, 1);
            printMatch("Local Area Code", m, 2);
            printMatch("Number", m, 3);
        }
    }
    public static void printMatch(String label, Matcher m, int group) {
        System.out.printf("%-16s: %s%n", label, m.group(group));
    }
}
```

yielding

```
Country Code    : 1
Local Area Code : 234
Number          : 5678900
```